# PolarRuntimeException in the SqlAlchemy +Python + Flask

Tags: sqlalchemy, oso

I am querying on the table project and filtering it by member_id using sqlalchemy.
As the number of records increases in the table, the query is taking more than 30 seconds to process. I tried to increase the connect_timeout, but it doesn't help.

```
  projects = g.auth_session.query(Project).filter_by(org_id=org_name).all()
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3373, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3531, in __iter__
    context = self._compile_context()
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 4069, in _compile_context
    new_query = fn(self)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/events.py", line 2719, in wrap
    return fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy_oso/session.py", line 51, in _before_compile
    return _authorize_query(query)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy_oso/session.py", line 81, in _authorize_query
    authorized_filter = authorize_model(oso, user, action, query.session, entity)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy_oso/auth.py", line 82, in authorize_model
    for result in results:
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/polar/polar.py", line 141, in query
    for res in Query(query, host=host, bindings=bindings).run():
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/polar/query.py", line 45, in run
    ffi_event = self.ffi_query.next_event()
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/polar/ffi.py", line 92, in next_event
    event = check_result(event)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/polar/ffi.py", line 152, in check_result
    raise Error().get()
polar.exceptions.PolarRuntimeError: Query timeout: Query running for 30. Exceeded query timeout of 30 seconds
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious whether the problem is in SQLA or Oso, so a good first step would be to see if the problem occurs if you remove all the Oso stuff.  If it does, then you may need to add some indexes to your database.  If it doesn't then the problem may be on the Oso side.